# Specify alpha for KOLMOGOROV-SMIRNOV TEST in SAS

Tags: sas, distribution, alpha

I am trying to compare distribution of 2 samples to see whether they are alike and am running the KS test as below:

For my real life data, the p value was less than .05 (assuming that this is the default alpha) indicating i could reject the null hypothesis. However, before concluding that I wanted to try the test at a different level of significance say .01, but for some reason I get the same value and an error when I specify "alpha=.01"

"WARNING: The ALPHA= option in the PROC NPAR1WAY statement is used only for Hodges-Lehmann confidence limits."

```
OPTIONS LS=72 PS=66 NONUMBER NODATE;
DATA IN; INPUT RESP SAMPLE $ @@; CARDS;
20.30 1 22.53 1 25.70 1 13.23 1 29.67 1 24.46 1
26.07 1 19.35 1 17.813 1 16.00 1 15.30 1 32.90 1
10.56 2 28.13 2 19.94 2 11.03 2 8.093 2 12.95 2
21.14 2 32.50 2 10.90 2
;

PROC NPAR1WAY DATA=IN EDF;
CLASS SAMPLE; VAR RESP; EXACT KS alpha=.01;
RUN;
```

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the alpha come into play? It's only the p-value that matters -unless I'm missing something, which is entirely possible.

Comment: the p-value will have an alpha (significance level) usually .05 based on which you'd reject/accept the hypothesis. Im guessing by default its 5%. I'd like to test 1% and 10% to see if that makes any difference

Comment: Try reading the online documentation for `proc npar1way`, I found the answer in less than 1 minute

Comment: SAS calculates a p-value. The p-value is the same regardless of alpha. You compare the p-value to alpha to determine significance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `/` to indicate the alpha is an option in the exact statement. It doesn't affect your p-value but does affect the confidence intervals.

```
PROC NPAR1WAY DATA=IN EDF;
CLASS SAMPLE;
VAR RESP; 
EXACT KS /alpha=0.05;
RUN;
```

Comment: Reeza, thanks. the / I had figured out since SAS won't run the code without the correct specification. this Alpha, like you said, only influences the confidence intervals. I am under the impression that when you specify alpha, e.g. in Proc GLM and some other procedures, the p-value is different depending on the alpha - is that an incorrect understanding of how SAS works?

Comment: That is incorrect. Alpha does not affect p-value, only confidence intervals.